# WireGuard: what is the default value/behavior for AllowedIPs

Tags: routing, wireguard

I'm trying to understand the use of `AllowedIPs` in WireGuard, because I had trouble with route setting under wireguard-relayed scenario.  An simplified example:

Server side:

```
[Interface]
Address = 172.16.23.1/32
PrivateKey = ...
ListenPort = ...

[Peer]
PublicKey = ...
AllowedIPs = 172.16.23.0/24
```

Client side:

```
[Interface]
Address = 172.16.23.100/32
PrivateKey = ...

[Peer]
PublicKey = ...
Endpoint = ...
AllowedIPs = 172.16.23.0/24
PersistentKeepalive = 45
```

My question is, can I omit `AllowedIPs` all together and set routes using linux `ip` command.

Comment: perhaps read some [documentation](https://www.wireguard.com/#cryptokey-routing)

Comment: half an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) (that is caused by not knowing about crytokeyrouting in Jaromanda X 's link).  Guessing the issue:  Y: can I remove AllowedIPs and set routes myself? X: I have a problem with the routes added when using AllowedIPs which conflict with an other special setup I create separately.  . Answer to Y: no you can't. Answer to X: you can make wg-quick not add the routes. I have an answer ready for X, but I'm not sure the problem is really X.